# How to convert uint256 to bytes, and bytes convert to uint256

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, remix

I want to send a series of numbers or letters like "aa5glegd...." for 44 byte as uint256 to call method, and in that method change it to bytes, then convert bytes to uint256.

Answer (score 3):

Using assembly

```
function toBytes(uint256 x) returns (bytes b) {
b = new bytes(32);
assembly { mstore(add(b, 32), x) }
}
```

Found reference here- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4170/how-to-convert-a-uint-to-bytes-in-solidity